# Difference between Solomon's problem instances

Tags: vehicle-routing, test-instances

I am in the process of solving the VRP and I have a set of Solomon test instances to test my program.

I actually found a test set with `C101, C102, ...`, `R101, R102, ...` and `RC201, RC202, ...`.

My question is what is the difference or the characteristics of each set (`C`, `R`, and `RC`) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good description of different problem instances [here](http://www.bernabe.dorronsoro.es/vrp/). From the link:

> ...benchmark problems (Solomon, 1987) composed of six different problem types (C1,C2,R1,R2,RC1,RC2). Each data set contains between eight to twelve 100-node problems. The names of the six problem types have the following meaning. Sets C have clustered customers whose time windows were generated based on a known solution. Problem sets R have customers location generated uniformly randomly over a square. Sets RC have a combination of randomly placed and clustered customers. Sets of type 1 have narrow time windows and small vehicle capacity. Sets of type 2 have large time windows and large vehicle capacity. Therefore, the solutions of type 2 problems have very few routes and significantly more customers per route.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, it is very helpful. I have a question, since the solomon instances contain the time windows and the vehicle capacity, are the solomon instances the most suitable data for testing the CVRP?

Comment: They are definitely the most widely known dataset but it depends on your use-case and the attributes you need. There are other datasets too. I gathered some of the other datasets [here](https://github.com/ekhoda/optimization_problem_libraries#vehicle-routing-problems). Check them and their description to see which ones suit you better.

Comment: I would also take a look at the CVRP library at the link. It is quite nicely organised with separate solution files and plots of solutions: http://vrp.atd-lab.inf.puc-rio.br/index.php/en/